# Why does Java display 10 digit numbers in scientific notation?

Tags: java, swing, ms-access

I have retrieved a large number from an Access database. Why does Java display this 10 digit no. as E+9 in its cells, instead of displaying the full number, even though i am using "Number" as datatype for that column.

Is there any way to display the full number instead of E+" " in the cells, other than using the "Text" datatype. If there is no way, how should a long no. coded from Java program be retrieved from database?

For eg :- 9867605659 will be displayed as E+9 using Number datatype, which may be entered as long from a java program, how to fetch it back from the database and set it to a textfield as 9867605659?

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import net.java.dev.designgridlayout.DesignGridLayout;
import java.io.*;
import net.java.dev.designgridlayout.Tag;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;  
import java.sql.*;

class Driverproblem
{
JFrame JF;
JDesktopPane JDP;
JInternalFrame JIF4,JIF13;
Container C,C4,C13;
JMenu FileMenu;
JMenuItem Settings,CompanyInfo;
JMenuBar JMB;
JLabel i4l1,i4l2,i4l3,i4l4,i4l5,i4l6,i4l7,i13l1,i13l2,i13l3,i13l4,i13l5,i13l6,i13l7;
JTextField i4t1,i4t2,i4t3,i4t4,i4t5,i4t6,i13t1,i13t2,i13t3,i13t4,i13t5,i13t6;
JButton i4b1,i13b1;
JTextArea i4ta1,i13ta1;
Color color;
public Driverproblem()
{
JF=new JFrame("Quick Accounting");
JDP=new JDesktopPane();
JMB=new JMenuBar();

C=JF.getContentPane();
color = Color.lightGray;
JDP.setBackground(color);
C.add(JDP,BorderLayout.CENTER);
C.add(JMB, BorderLayout.NORTH);
JF.pack();
JF.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
JF.setVisible(true);

FileMenu=new JMenu("File"); 

CompanyInfo=new JMenuItem("Company Info");

CompanyInfo.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
    JIF4.setVisible(true);
    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection i4conn =        DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:TomsJava");
        PreparedStatement i4ps = i4conn.prepareStatement("select * from i13SaveUserSettings");      
ResultSet i4rs =     i4ps.executeQuery();
        while(i4rs.next())
        {
            String i4companyName = i4rs.getString("Company_Name");
            String i4address = i4rs.getString("Address");
            String i4place = i4rs.getString("Place");
            long i4phone = i4rs.getLong("Phone");
            int i4pincode = i4rs.getInt("Pincode");
            String i4email = i4rs.getString("Email");
            String i4website = i4rs.getString("Website");
            System.out.println(i4phone);

            i4t1.setText(i4companyName);
            i4ta1.setText(i4address);
            i4t2.setText(i4place);
            i4t4.setText(String.valueOf(i4phone));
            i4t4.setText(String.valueOf(i4pincode));
            i4t5.setText(i4email);
            i4t6.setText(i4website);                
        }
        i4rs.close();
        i4ps.close();
        i4conn.close();


    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException z)
    {
        System.out.println(z);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException n)
    {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
});
  JIF4 = new JInternalFrame("Company Information",true,true, true, true);  
 JIF4.setBounds(10, 10, 600, 500); 
    C4 = JIF4.getContentPane();
DesignGridLayout layout4 = new DesignGridLayout(C4);

    i4l1 = new JLabel("Company Name : ");
    i4l2 = new JLabel("Address : ");
    i4l3 = new JLabel("Place : ");
    i4l4 = new JLabel("Phone : ");
    i4l5 = new JLabel("Pincode : ");
    i4l6 = new JLabel("Email : ");
    i4l7 = new JLabel("Website : ");
    i4t1 = new JTextField(20);
    i4t2 = new JTextField(20);
    i4t3 = new JTextField(20);
    i4t4 = new JTextField(20);
    i4t5 = new JTextField(20);
    i4t6 = new JTextField(20);
    i4ta1 = new JTextArea(5,20);
    i4b1 = new JButton("Close");
i4b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
    JIF4.dispose();
    }
});


layout4.row().grid(i4l1).add(i4t1);
layout4.row().grid(i4l2).add(i4ta1);
layout4.row().grid(i4l3).add(i4t2);
layout4.row().grid(i4l4).add(i4t3);
layout4.row().grid(i4l5).add(i4t4);
layout4.row().grid(i4l6).add(i4t5);
layout4.row().grid(i4l7).add(i4t6);
layout4.emptyRow();
layout4.row().center().add(i4b1);
JDP.add(JIF4);


Settings=new JMenuItem("Settings");
Settings.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
    JIF13.setVisible(true);
    }
});
JIF13 = new JInternalFrame("User Settings",true,true, true, true);  
JIF13.setBounds(10, 10, 600, 500); 

    C13 = JIF13.getContentPane();
DesignGridLayout layout13 = new DesignGridLayout(C13);

    i13l1 = new JLabel("Company Name : ");
    i13l2 = new JLabel("Address : ");
    i13l3 = new JLabel("Place : ");
    i13l4 = new JLabel("Phone : ");
    i13l5 = new JLabel("Pincode : ");
    i13l6 = new JLabel("Email : ");
    i13l7 = new JLabel("Website : ");
    i13t1 = new JTextField(20);
    i13t2 = new JTextField(20);
    i13t3 = new JTextField(20); 
    i13t4 = new JTextField(20);
    i13t5 = new JTextField(20);
    i13t6 = new JTextField(20);
    i13ta1 = new JTextArea(5,20);
    i13b1 = new JButton("Save");
i13b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
            try
        {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection i13conn = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:TomsJava");

        String i13companyName = i13t1.getText();
        String i13address = i13ta1.getText();
        String i13place = i13t2.getText();
        long i13phone = Long.valueOf(i13t3.getText());
        int i13pincode = Integer.parseInt(i13t4.getText());
        String i13email = i13t5.getText();
        String i13website = i13t6.getText();

        Statement i13stmt = i13conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet i13rs = i13stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM i13SaveUserSettings");
        i13rs.absolute(1);
        i13rs.updateString("Company_Name", i13companyName);
        i13rs.updateString("Address",i13address);
        i13rs.updateString("Place",i13place);
        i13rs.updateLong("Phone",i13phone);
        i13rs.updateInt("Pincode",i13pincode);
        i13rs.updateString("Email",i13email);
        i13rs.updateString("Website",i13website);
        i13rs.insertRow();

        i13rs.close();
        i13stmt.close();

        }       

    catch(SQLException e)
    {
    System.out.println(e);
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException z)
    {
    System.out.println(z);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException n)
    {
    System.out.println(n);
    }
    JIF13.dispose();
    }
});


layout13.row().grid(i13l1).add(i13t1);
layout13.row().grid(i13l2).add(i13ta1);
layout13.row().grid(i13l3).add(i13t2);
layout13.row().grid(i13l4).add(i13t3);
layout13.row().grid(i13l5).add(i13t4);
layout13.row().grid(i13l6).add(i13t5);
layout13.row().grid(i13l7).add(i13t6);
layout13.emptyRow();
layout13.row().center().add(i13b1);

JDP.add(JIF13);

FileMenu.add(Settings);
FileMenu.add(CompanyInfo);
JMB.add(FileMenu);
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException
{
new Driverproblem();
}
```

}

Comment: why is Java tagged in this??

Comment: i asked java code for fetching database cells.

Comment: What is the `Field Size` for the [Phone] and [Pincode] fields in the Access table? (My guess is that they are `Double`.)

Comment: @gordThompson - They are set to Long Integer. it happens only when i enter 10 digit, displays for 9 digit.

Comment: Umm, you cannot put 9867605659 into an Access `Long Integer` field. The largest value for that field type is 2147483647.

Comment: Using `Double` would make it *more* likely that the "numbers" would appear in scientific notation, and would introduce other complications as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue stems from the fact that you are apparently trying to store [Phone] as a `Number`. While we tend to call them "phone numbers" they are really just strings of digits. They are not "numbers" in the mathematical sense because we have no need to perform calculations on them. (For example, adding or subtracting two phone numbers serves no useful purpose.)

So, you should simply use a `Text` field in the Access database to store [Phone] (and probably use a `Text` field for [Pincode], too).

**edit re: comment**

Regarding the display of very large (or very small) numbers, there are several factors that could cause a number to appear in scientific notation. For example, when displaying a very large number in a text box the UI code could switch the number to scientific notation

- if the value has more than a given number of significant digits, or
- if the text box is too narrow to display the entire number in standard notation then the UI code might opt for scientific notation instead of truncating the value (or producing an "overflow" display like `#######`).

Certainly floating-point types like `Double` and `Single` are the most likely to appear in scientific notation because their range of values is so large that at some point we'd be forced to use it. This can be illustrated with the following Java code, where both fields in the Access table contain `12345678`

```java
ps = con.prepareStatement(
        String.format("SELECT DoubleField, LongIntField FROM DemoTable WHERE ID=1")
        );
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
rs.next();
System.out.println(rs.getDouble(1));
System.out.println(rs.getInt(2));
System.out.println(9223372036854775807L);
```

The console output is

```
1.2345678E7
12345678
9223372036854775807
```

Notice that the [DoubleField] value is displayed in scientific notation even though it takes *more* space than the standard notation equivalent would (`12345678.0`). Java has apparently decided that the number is "big enough" to warrant switching to scientific notation. Notice also that Java happily prints out the largest possible `Long` value, even though it is *much* larger than the `Double` value.

Comment: the point which you have said is very good & solves my problem here, but just for sake of my knowledge, want to know how to deal with such big numbers.

Comment: Thanks Gord Thompson.

Comment: To deal with large numbers? My article on rounding in Access here will give you some tips: http://www.kallal.ca/Articles/rounding/Rounding.html